# MVC/Razor Passing form variables to a chart image method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have updated the code, but am still running into problems... I think I'm lost in spaghetti code at the moment.

My financial periods controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetChartImage(bool checkedCash, bool checkedPrepaidExpenses)          
    {
            var sql = String.Format("select * from FinancialPeriods");
            var chartData = db.FinancialPeriods.SqlQuery(sql);
            var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400);                       
            myChart.AddSeries(name: "Prepaid Expenses", chartType: "Line", xValue: chartData, xField: "Year", yValues: chartData, yFields: "PrepaidExpenses");
           /* 
           if (checkedCash)
            {
                myChart.AddSeries(name: "Cash", chartType: "Line", xValue: chartData, xField: "Year", yValues: chartData, yFields: "Cash").AddLegend("Legend");
            }
          */
            return File(myChart.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/bytes");


    }
    //bool checkedCash, bool checkedPrepaidExpenses
    public ActionResult Chart(bool checkedCash, bool checkedExpenses)
    {
        ViewBag.CheckedCash = checkedCash;
        ViewBag.CheckedExpenses = checkedExpenses;           
        var sql = String.Format("select * from FinancialPeriods");
        var chartData = db.FinancialPeriods.SqlQuery(sql);
        var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400);     
        if (checkedCash)
        {
            myChart.AddSeries(name: "Cash", chartType: "Line", xValue: chartData, xField: "Year", yValues: chartData, yFields: "Cash").AddLegend("Legend");
        }

        return PartialView("_Chart"); // returns a partial view of the chart based on the model
    }
```

My INDEX View:

```
                <tr><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="updatechart" value="Update Chart"></td></tr>
            </table>

        </p>
    </div>
}




        <div id="graphRight"> @Html.Action("GetChartImage", new {    checkedCash = false, checkedPrepaidExpenses = false })</div>

 </div>
 <script src ="/assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
     var url = '@Url.Action("Chart")';
  var imgcontainer = $('graphRight');
  $('#updatechart').click(function () {
    var isCash = $('#checkedCash').is(':checked');
    var isExpenses = $('#checkedPrepaidExpenses').is(':checked');
    imgcontainer.load(url, { checkedCash: isCash, checkedPrepaidExpenses:    isExpenses });


});
</script>
```

_Chart.cshtml (shared)

```
  @model IEnumerable<FinancialAnalysisSite.Models.FinancialPeriod>

 <img src="@Url.Action("Chart", new { checkedCash = ViewBag.CheckedCash,    checkedPrepaidExpenses = ViewBag.checkedPrepaidExpenses })" />
```

I have updated the code, but am still running into problems... I think I'm lost in spaghetti code at the moment.

Comment: You will need to use javascript/jquery to build a url based on the form values

Comment: Have a good reference? Have been doing this JavaScript free. Btw I saw a piece I think you did on code project I think it was. Nice job.

Comment: Just noticed its in an img tag. Are you wanting to update your chart based on the value of the checkboxes? - in which case it would be best to use ajax to post the values to a controller method that returns a partial view of the new chart and then update the DOM

Comment: Sorry... again I've gotta ask for a reference. Have any dark age stuff I could use? Got a Friday deadline for this stuff. AJAX would be fancy, I admit. *chuckle*

Comment: Asking for a reference is off topic for SO. Happy to give you an example if the assumption in my last comment is correct.

Comment: You are correct- I do want to update the chart based on the value of the checkboxes. If you have an example that would be much appreciated, chief.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to call a controller method that returns a partial view of the updated chart. Assuming you have a controller method

```
public ActionResult Chart(bool checkedCash, bool checkedExpenses)
{
  ViewBag.CheckedCash = checkedCash;
  ViewBag.CheckedExpenses = checkedExpenses;
  return PartialView("_Chart"); // returns a partial view of the chart based on the model
}
```

and the `_Chart.cshtml` view

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetChartImage", new { checkedCash = ViewBag.CheckedCash, checkedPrepaidExpenses = checkedExpenses })"/>
```

which in turn calls your `GetChartImage()` to generate the chart. Note the return type of your method should be

```
return File(chart, "image/bytes");
```

Then in the view, include a button to update the chart

```
<button type="button" id="updatechart">Update chart</button>
```

and include a script to handle the buttons `.click()` event and update the DOM using the jquery `.load()` method.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Chart")';
var imgcontainer = $('graphRight');
$('#updatechart').click(function() {
  var isCash = $('#checkedCash').is(':checked');
  var isExpenses = $('#checkedExpenses').is(':checked');
  imgcontainer.load(url, { checkedCash: isCash, checkedExpenses: isExpenses  });
});
```

Note the code for generating the initial image could then use the same method using `@Html.Action()` (passing in whatever default values are necessary)

```
<div id="graphRight">@Html.Action("Chart", new { checkedCash = false, checkedExpenses = false })</div>
```

Comment: Holy moly. *chuckle* Wow... you want me to paypal you like $15 or something? Well done. It's midnight here, but I'm going to give that a whirl first thing tmw morning. Will be sure to credit you with answer! Thanks, Stephen!

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'

Comment: Any idea about that exception? ^

Comment: It's highlighting: @Html.Action("GetChartImage", new { checkedCash = false, checkedPrepaidExpenses = false }) "

Comment: Can't seem to post full code example here. I posted here:

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/2055261.aspx?+Error+executing+child+request+for+handler+System+Web+Mvc+HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper+

Comment: There a few possible reasons - the  most common is a circular reference (the partial view contains a call to the partial view). Can you edit your question to include the `GetChartImage.cshtml` code. Also from the link, your have 2 `<div id="graphRight">` - the first one (with the `<img>` tag) needs to be deleted.

Comment: I added the code... I have the GetChartImage method inside my FinancialPeriodsController.cs file (which is my index).

Comment: Sorry the formatting is off... it won't let me fix it for some reason at the moment.

Comment: Fixed the formatting for you but I need to see the partial view - the fact you have called it `Index` suggest some problems (is that the same as the main view?)

Comment: OK, based on your `GetChartImage()` method I think I understand the issue. In my code `GetChartImage()` was a method that returned a partial view containing just the `<img>` tag - sorry for not explaining better. I have updated my answer to give the complete solution and renamed the methods so its clearer

Comment: Note also the error you were getting was as a result of a circular reference. In the (revised) view you had `@Html.Action()` which calls `GetChartImage()` which returned a view (`Index`) which (assuming that is the initial view) contains `@Html.Action()`, which calls `GetChartImage()` which contains `@Html.Action()` which calls `GetChartImage()` and so on and so on until it spits the dummy :)

Comment: Sorry bud, I'm still running into problems. I posted my current code, but I think I'm lost in spaghetti code at the moment. Any ideas would be appreciated. =/

Comment: Your edited code is still not correct. The `Chart()` method needs to be as per my code (just the 3 lines of code) and ditto the `_Chart.cshtml` needs to be just the one line of code as per my answer.